# A system sound ignores volume level

Tags: iphone, volume, system-sounds

I am working on the game. And I have some issue with sounds.

I use system sounds to acknowledge a player, when he/she presses a button. These sounds respect the volume set by a player, when other sounds are playing (I use `AVAudioPlayer`s and `AudioQueue`s). But when a system sound is only to play, it ignore a volume set by player and plays at a ringer's volume.

How to force system sounds to respect a volume set by a player even when is no other sounds played?

Comment: this is an old issue, but have you considered having a dummy AVAudioPlayer running in the background (a very short sample with a looping player). it's silly and a waste of resources, but it should do the trick. also: yes, this is annoying!

Comment: @Aleksejs: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem, and I'd like to avoid the AVAudioPlayer hack if possible.

Comment: @Michael Noup, I'm using `AVAudioPlayer` for background music constantly. I don't know other solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are your players (I assume you mean the people playing the game) setting the volume -- through the device's volume control, or through your app interface? If the latter, then this won't work, since system sounds should always play at the device volume.

According to the [Multimedia Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW1), "Sounds play at the current system audio volume, with no programmatic volume control available."

I don't know why your system sounds would change volume when an AVAudioPlayer sound is playing. If that's the case, can you loop a silent sound with AVAudioPlayer when you're not playing other sounds? Otherwise I would try playing all sounds with AVAudioPlayer so that you have direct control over the volume.

Comment: A player can control volume with volume buttons on the side of iPhone.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are meaning that players are setting the volume using the side volume buttons on the device:

I had the same problem getting SystemSound to respect the volume buttons but found a setting in "Settings"/"Sounds"/"Ringer and Alerts"/"Change With Buttons" that was "OFF" by default. Switching that  to "ON" made it work.

Comment: I hope Apple didn't quietly disable that setting in an iOS update to show off the feature. I can see how it would be useful in rare cases, but it was a PITA for me.